# My Twitter bot is meant to go through my timeline and follow people that I do not follow already but it produces a 403 error without following anyone

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

The challenge I am having is that when the code runs, it tries to follow the same people it has already followed, then eventually brings an error on one person I already follow.
I would want it to run through the time, look at tweets, and follow those people that I am not following.

My code seems to be ok but it's not following anyone.

```
def follow_tl_users():
    user =api.verify_credentials()  
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.home_timeline).items(50):
        if not tweet.user.following or tweet.user.id != user.id:
            tweet.user.follow()
            print("followed: "+ tweet.user.screen_name)
    time.sleep(10)
```

It also brings a 403 forbidden error.

Kindly help me understand what I'm getting wrong.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be with the `or` because the condition will always be `True` when the user isn't the authorized user. It seems like this would be better:

```py
if not tweet.user.following and tweet.user.id != user.id:
```

Notice that the `and` replaces the `or` because both conditions need to be `True` if you want to only follow people you aren't already following and don't want the authorized user to follow themselves.

Comment: Thank you @joe Mayo,  I have tweaked the code but this time, it doesn't do anything at all. It just runs for a few seconds and stops without doing anything.

Comment: After removing the items argument, it returns this: Rate limit reached. Sleeping for: 715. However, I haven't followed anyone new. So I'm wondering how it has reached the limit without following anyone.

Comment: An easier way to test and debug might be to create a test user account where you can limit the number of followers that you can follow/unfollow without affecting real accounts. This will let you print out more info to make debugging easier. The rate limit is 15 requests every 15 minutes, which means it could take a long time to test (maybe hours) if you have a lot of followers.